# Google Maps API v3 acceps only "google_map" element ID

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I need to show multiple maps on my website, but the API works only if map container has ID "google_map". I cannot use any other IDs.
Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you create the map object

`var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"))`

hook it to the corresponding div

`<div id="map_canvas"></div>`

You can create as many map objects as you'd like:

`var mapTwo = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_two"))`

`<div id="map_canvas_two"></div>`

Comment: That is obvious, but map wouldn't initialize if the element has ID different than "google_map" that's the problem

Comment: `var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   var pos = new google.maps.LatLng($("#lat_"+oid).val(), $("#long_"+oid).val());
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: pos})
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map"), {mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP});
   bounds.extend(pos);
   map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
   marker.setMap(map);`  
`<div id=\"google_map\"></div>`

Comment: Each instance of Map needs to have a unique ID. If you need multiple maps on the same page you need two unique ID's. are you trying to set multiple _markers_ on one map?

Comment: I have unique IDs (when I have more maps) but if I have just one map, it doesn't work if ID is different than "google_map", so that I cannot use more maps, because I cannot set more IDs